# Can a template be instantiated if there is nested type (not accessed) with a method that cannot be compiled?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++

I accidentally found that g++ (5.2.0) compiles the following

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    int x;
    struct B {
        void foo() {
            x = 1;
        }
    };
};
```

even istantiating `A` and `A::B`, provided the member `B::foo` is not used. You reasonably get instead a compile error for `x` being a non-static member of `A` even by just compiling the no-op statement `&A<int>::B::foo;`.

clang (3.6.2) however refuses the template even if `A` is not instantiated at all because it says that the non-static member name `x` cannot be used inside `B` while just reading the template definition.

Is this a bug in g++ or clang is being too strict about template members that are not instantiated?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but could it be that g++ is assuming int for non-declared x?

Comment: @A.S.H: no because `x` resolves to `A::x`. If you try to make any reference to method `A<T>::B::foo` (even just taking its address and dropping it) the error message agrees with `clang`. If you write `z = 1` instead of `x = 1` moreover `g++` too raises the error immediately about the unknown `z`.

Comment: I believe the compiler is allowed, but not required, to diagnose that a template cannot be instantiated for any `T`. (No quote from the standard available.)

Comment: @BoPersson: `g++` however instantiates `A` and even `A::B` without problems if you don't use `A::B::foo`. You can get a working executable with 0 warnings under `-Wall`. I suppose this is a `g++` bug, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Uninstantiated members are checked for syntax only, not for *semantic*..and `x=1;` is a valid syntax, though invalid semantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` in your code is a non-dependent name, and the Standard renders a template that cannot be validly instantiated whatever you provide as template parameter as ill-formed, no diagnostic required (actually this also applies to "temploids", as an example in the Standard shows. That is, the rules apply equally well to members of class templates).

Your code is as invalid as any normal class that accesses a name of a surrounding class. Notice that the direction is important here. The following would *not* be ill-formed (because you *can* specialize `A<T>::B` such that `x` for `A<int>::B` is a static member, for example.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
    struct B {
       int x;
    };

    void f() {
       B::x = 1;
    }
};
```

However, an *enclosing* class template's type is called *the current instantiation*, which means that its meaning always stays the same and cannot change depending on template parameters. Therefore the template definition itself can be rendered ill-formed by certain uses such as yours.

Comment: "_you can specialize A<T>::B_" how would you do that?

Comment: @curiousguy `template<> struct A<int>::B { }`.

Comment: So IIUC `clang++` is right in complaining but `g++` is not wrong in saying everything is ok. Correct?

Comment: Ok, makes sense. It also makes sense that no diagnostic is required as proving that no instantiation is possible smells of halting problem.

Comment: @6502 because I wanted to visualize how far in reaching the minimal-characters-in-comment limit I was. It was not a pun about your nick-name.

Answer (score 1):

[temp.res]/8 says:

> No diagnostic
>   shall be issued for a template for which a valid specialization can be generated. If no valid specialization can
>   be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.

I believe the second sentence applies to unused parts of `B`. If the function is not instantiated, the compiler is not required to realize that it cannot be instantiated, ever.